# CRC - uint64 to two bytes?

Tags: go, type-conversion, byte, crc, uint64

I am using [this](https://github.com/snksoft/crc) CRC package to calculate XMODEM CCITT crc values for messages.  The crc values are uint64s, and the author demonstrates *printing* the hex value of the CRC code as two bytes using

```
// crc1 is a uint64
fmt.Printf("CRC is 0x%04X\n", crc1) // prints "CRC is 0x2C89"
```

How do I convert this to two bytes without making it a string and splitting it?  `%04X` is base-16 two characters per byte, if I understand the fmt docs properly.

I only know a few things: (1), that the hardware I am writing an adapter for expects two bytes for the CRC value. (2), that the author of this CRC package shows that the uint64 can be displayed as 0xFFFF, which is two bytes. (3), that online CRC calculators show these values as two bytes, e.g. https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html. The rest is new to me...

I just posted a snippet from the readme of the CRC package. Since a uint64 would normally be 8 bytes, I really do not understand how this can be done without data loss.

Comment: If crc is 2-bytes, then the upper 6 bytes of the int64 value are all 0s.

Comment: @bserdar 's comment explains that the upper 6 bytes of the uint64 CRC are zero (so there is no risk of data loss), and his answer explains how to convert the uint64 CRC into two bytes. Note that snksoft/crc/crc.go includes a CRC16() function that shows how to typecast between uint64 and uint16.

Answer (score 1):

> On-line CRC calculation and free library
>
> https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html
>
> LibCRC – Open Source CRC Library in C
>
> https://www.libcrc.org/api-reference/
>
> https://github.com/lammertb/libcrc/blob/master/src/crc16.c
>
> ```
> /*
>  * uint16_t crc_16( const unsigned char *input_str, size_t num_bytes );
>  *
>  * The function crc_16() calculates the 16 bits CRC16 in one pass for a byte
>  * string of which the beginning has been passed to the function. The number of
>  * bytes to check is also a parameter. The number of the bytes in the string is
>  * limited by the constant SIZE_MAX.
>  */
>
> uint16_t crc_16( const unsigned char *input_str, size_t num_bytes ) {
>
> // code Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Lammert Bies
>
> }  /* crc_16 */
> ```

---

C type `uint16_t` is Go type `uint16`.

`uint16 = uint16(uint64)`

`crc16 =  0xFFBB = uint16(0x000000000000000FFBB)`

`crc16[0], crc16[1] = byte(uint64>>8), byte(uint64)`

`crc16[0], crc16[1] = 0xFF, 0xBB 
     = byte(0x000000000000000FFBB>>8), byte(0x000000000000000FFBB)`

---

References:

CRC-16-CCITT : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

XModem Protocol with CRC: http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/amulet/xmodem.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you're trying to get the two lowest bytes of an int64 value, or if you want to get two strings with two hex digits each. In any case:

```
b1:=byte(crc1>>8)
b2:=byte(crc1&0xFF)

str1:=fmt.Sprintf("%02X",b1)
str2:=fmt.Sprintf("%02X",b2)
```

Or

```
crc:=uint16(crc1)
```

Above, crc is 2-bytes.

Comment: If you need a two byte value, then uint16(crc1) is what you need. But if you're writing this to some hardware, you need to figure out if this is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: The hardware takes a datastream which is little endian, followed by big endian CRC.  /IF/ loss of "range" is the only mechanism and it is not something more clever, then I can just `encoding/binary.BigEndian.PutUvarInt` the uint64...

Comment: @BrandonDube - When a CRC is used with a datastream, the first byte is most significant, and the last byte is least significant. The CRC is appended to a datastream most significant byte first, least significant byte last. The bits within each byte may be reflected, which is generally done if the bits in each byte (including the bits in the CRC bytes) are transmitted least significant bit first. This allows hardware to encode / decode 1 bit at a time while transmitting or receiving a datastream + CRC in real time.